# Oauth 2 with Client Credentials Flow - Is it safe to assume subject will always be null?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I have an API which takes access tokens which can be provided by either Implicit or Client Credentials grant types.

It would be useful for me to know, by inspecting the access token, which grant type is being used (It will allow me to make some optimizations in our authentication code).

What I have read here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/76
suggests to me that if the subject isn't provided in the access token, it can be assumed that it's the client credentials flow. At least with Identity Server.

My question is, is this a safe assumption to make, regardless of the Authorization Server?